# How to embed a long list of integers as a Resource in a native c++ Windows application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resources, embedded-resource

I am creating a native C++ application in Visual Studio (2013). I have a very long file (10000+) of comma separated integers that I must include in my exe-file. My first attempt was to `#include` a file that defined a native int array as follows

```
int MYINTEGERS[] = { 12, 45, 88, .... very long list  };
```

but that file took "hours" to compile.

my current approach is to make a so called *user-defined raw-data resource.*  [defined here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381054(v=vs.85).aspx) . Thus, I have created a text file containing the following:

```
MyNameID MyTypeID { 12, 45, 88, .... very long list }
```

**But how should I proceed, in Visual Studio**, to make the resource compiler (RC) compile that file and include it in my binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your user defined resource in a resource (*.rc) file, or copy the resource definition into a resource file of your project. If it exists, you should be able to find in Solution Explorer under `Resources` folder. It it does not exist, add your newly created file to this folder. Then, if you do not have a header for resource defines (usually called `Resource.h`), create one and add the following line to it:

```
#define MyNameID    1000
```

Note that you can place any constant instead of 1000, as long as it is not the same as some constant used for some other resource. Finally, you can access your array in the program using `FindResource` Win32 function:

```
HRSRC hResource = FindResourceW(m_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(MyNameID), L"MyTypeID");
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine when I opened the rc-file in notepad!